# visual studio setup project rebuild error

Tags: git, visual-studio

When I'm trying to rebuild the setup project I'm getting an error: `could not find file`. I have verified my target version is correct and pointing to sql server 2016 (was pointing to sql server 2019) rebuild the solution and everything and still get this. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.4.5

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Integration Services Project2 (SQL Server 2016), Configuration: Development ------
Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Full ...
Starting project consistency check ...
Project consistency check completed. The project is consistent.
File 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\Integration Services Project2\obj\Development\Integration Services Project2.dtproj' get updated.
File 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\Integration Services Project2\obj\Development\Project.params' get updated.
File 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\Integration Services Project2\obj\Development\Package.dtsx' get updated.
Applied active configuration to 'Project.params'.
Applied active configuration to 'Package.dtsx'.
Integration Services Project2 -> C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\Integration Services Project2\bin\Development\Integration Services Project2.ispac
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'dataimport' ------ 
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'dataimport' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'dataimport' completed ------
------ Pre-build validation for project 'dataimport' completed ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: dataimport, Configuration: Release ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: dataimport, Configuration: Release ------
Building file 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\dataimport\Release\dataimport.msi'...
Building file 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\dataimport\Release\dataimport.msi'...
ERROR: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\Integration Services Project2\bin\Package.dtsx' 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
ERROR: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Keith\source\repos\Integration Services Project2\bin\Package.dtsx' 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have been looking but not really finding any thing on this.

Thanks
Keith

Comment: RESOLVED... the build had put all the files in the following folder path \bin\Development\ and it was looking for the path of just \bin. moved the file into just \bin for now and resolved rebuild issue

Answer (score 0):

you can try using other version of visual studio perhaps that can help to resolve the issue at hand it

i tried using visual studio express edition
and i ended up having the error windows can not run this application "needs and updated version" 
and then i downloaded ultimate visual studio which actually solved my problem automatically 
 so  i believe the same might be the issue over there if not 
then follow the link
https://msdn.com/microsoft
and receive a solution 
thanks